# Application assembly name length limitation

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, filenames

Can anyone tell the reason behind WPF application supports maximum 40 characters as  assembly name length.

To reproduce the issue:

Create one WPF application with default template. Now change the assembly name to  "WpfApplication12345678912345678912345678", it works properly.

**How I have changed the Assembly Name**

1. Right click on WPF project
2. Select Properties
3. Go to Application tab
4. Changed the Assembly Name of the project to "WpfApplication12345678912345678912345678"

But when I append one more character to that "WpfApplication123456789123456789123456789" - it stops working.

**Note**: I am aware about the following message and above issue is not related to:

> "The length of the full path for the solution, project or item you are creating exceeds the maximum path length allowed by the system. You must reduce the length of the name or the location."

My project is @ Location: E:\ConsoleApplication3\WpfApplication1

Debug folder path : E:\ConsoleApplication3\WpfApplication1\bin\Debug

Application Exe in Debug folder: WpfApplication1.exe

Comment: _Why_ does the name need to be that long?

Comment: I am working on an enterprise application which already has that big namespace and I have to add one WPF application under that namespace and can't shorten it.

Comment: If you're having trouble *right now* on the development system with the filename being too long, think about what's going to happen when you *deploy* your application. Think about all the weired support calls about not being able to start the application; Because the application got installed into `C:\Program Files\Company Name\Company Application\Your Extra Super Long Module.exe`. This is not a fight worth fighting. Your reason related to `namespace` is not valid, because the `namespace` has nothing to do with the Module Name.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund: I don't have issue with namespace. I have issue with Assembly Name. And FYI that this issue is not coming when the application/project is a console application. This is specific for the WPF application only.

Comment: @MilanRaval: there is no need to add WPF to the front of the question. You can check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147063 "Should questions include “tags” in their titles?") for reference.

Comment: @Default: this is not just the question of adding tag. It is emphasis on the issue that comes only for WPF applications and not for other application. According to my knowledge tags are just reference to the technology you are asking about.

Comment: as I understand it the title should boil down to the core of the problem, exactly what the issue is without much detail really. if you give to much detail it will be harder to find by others because they have to search for the exact title your wrote. the reason there are two fields (title and body) is because you can add all the details in the body, including that it only relates to WPF applications. By the same reason you don't add "40 character limit" to the title, you keep it generic by stating "limitation".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had change Platform target to "Any CPU" and it solved the problem.

**Changed the Platform target from** 
Project Properties > Build > General Section > Platform target drop down.

Thank you all who tried to help me out.

Comment: "Any CPU" is the default, everyone that tried helping you and managed to reproduce the error used "Any CPU" as the target CPU. The target CPU only has a limited influence on the error, so this is not an answer to the asked question. And note, I don't doubt that the changed helped you. That doesn't make it a solution to the asked question.

Comment: Try by setting it to x86, you can produce the error at your end.

Answer (score 2):

In windows you have a maximum lenght for a path. The maximum-length is 256. You can have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Please read my note at the end of question, I am already aware about it

Comment: @MilanRaval, it's the same issue. Try creating your app in a folder with a shorter path and you'll see the IDE lets you create much longer names. For example, if I created the app under `D:\Temp` I was able to use this name: `WpfApp123456789101234567894562321548754231232456541111111` - much longer then your requested name.

Comment: its not a project name - its an assembly name. Go through the steps I have mentioned

Comment: Can you please post the target-path for you assembly and the assembly-name?

Comment: @MilanRaval, the assembly name **is** the application name. Here's the test I did. New WPF application, saved to short path (`D:\Temp\Y`), gave the solution a very short name (`Y`) and then changed the assembly name until I got an error. I ended up with this: `Y1234567890123456789102342342342342342342342342342342343234234223342234322243345345434544A1234567890123456789012345678890B12345`

Comment: You assumption that it isn't related to that specific message is wrong. Paths (drive:\directories\filename) can't be longer then 256 chars combined, so depending on where your project is located your filename will have to be limited. For example, C:\Users\Milan\Documents\Visual Studio 12\Projects\My.Really.Awesome.Enterprise.Solution\My.Really.Awesome.Enterprise.Solution.Networking.And.Data.Usage.Assembly\bin\x86\My.Really.Awesome.Enterprise.Solution.Networking.And.Data.Usage.Assembly.dll would almost hit the limit even though the filename is only 77 chars but with the path added, it is 247.

Comment: Think about what the IDE needs to do with your assembly name; It *needs* to create the file, it's going to create it in a sub-folder of your `target` folder under `obj\Debug\AssemblyName.Ext`, it will need to work with that. Start with a long target name and put a long assembly name in there and the full path to your assembly becomes very long.

Comment: @Karl-Johan Sjögren : I have edited my question with the paths.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund: I am aware about path length issue. It will be a good help if you follow the same steps to produce the issue as I have edited in my question.

Comment: @MilanRaval, I *did* follow your *exact* steps. Did you follow my example? Did you try creating a solution named `Y` in a very short path? Did you look on the disk drive to see the filenames generated? This is the longest file I got, before I bored: `D:\Temp\A\Y\Y\obj\Debug\Y1234567890123456789102342342342342342342342342342342343234234223342234322243345345434544A1234567890123456789012345678890B1234567890_MarkupCompile.i.cache` - it's 179 characters long. Who knows what other, longer files the IDE generates when you hit RUN.